# validation rule requires that only if lock down the picklist value once it has been set

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I was trying to write a validation rule , but it is not reflecting which I expected. 
There is a pick-list field having 6 values namely `active, processing, accepted,rejected, admitted, discharge`. Once the pick-list value has been saved as `admitted` we need to lock down this value for all users except system admin user.

I have been struck for the below validation rule. Can you please guide.

```
AND(
 PRIORVALUE(Status) = "Admitted", 
 NOT($User.Id = "005P00000015Vvm"),
 ISCHANGED(Status)
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what is not working. Your rule looks correct.

Comment: but it is not firing, I dont know why

Comment: Have you activated the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in multiple ways.

1. One of them is, you can change the record type to a Locked Type and
   assign a page layout where you don't allow the picklist to be edited
   further.
2. For the method that you are using you need to change the rule to
   this:

   ```
   AND(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Admitted"),
   ISCHANGED(Status),NOT($Profile.Name = "System Administrator"))
   ```

**You shouldn't hardcode the Ids in rules/code. Those might differ in other orgs.**